# Warm up database (put the whole db into cache)

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching, sql-server-2012

I've read a fair amount on this. but can't find a workable solution.  I have a server with plenty of RAM and a 10GB DB.  I want to load the entire DB (including indexes) into RAM/cache.

This solution doesn't seem to work: http://sqlsmurf.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/sql-warm-up-script/

Is there an way to load everything into RAM storage?  I could do `SELECT * FROM blah`, however that (I believe) wouldn't work as it wouldn't load the indexes properly, it would also be somewhat slow.

Comment: Could you run `UPDATE STATISTICS table WITH FULLSCAN` on all the tables?

Comment: What about defining a CACHE in your Domain Logic layer?

Comment: @MihaiBejenariu The application is a restful .NET application, I wouldn't want to start dealing with a localized cache at that layer unless the gains would be tremendous.

Comment: @Turophile - How exactly would that help?  I could run it (assuming it doesn't lock the tables, which I'm sure it doesn't), but would it load everything into the cache?

Comment: This sounds unnecessary. The DB will be brought gradually into cache when it is being used. Basically on the first access to a page that page is cached. Isn't that enough? Btw, "doesn't work" isn't a useful error description.

Comment: I believe that `UPDATE STATISTICS` will bring the table and indexes into the cache, but is a bit clumsy. @usr seems to have a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to bring something into cache (and there *are* use-cases for that, for example to shorten the time an offline index build takes), I use something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM T WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX(IndexNameHere))
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

And run that for each index. It doesn't get more efficient than this. The `NOLOCK` is there to get an IAM scan instead of a b-tree-order scan.

Still, I'd like to find out why you want this. The DB will be brought gradually into cache when it is being used. Basically on the first access to a page that page is cached. Isn't that enough?

Comment: The issue is, is that before being in the cache, some queries take around 3/4 seconds, in the cache they take 1/2 seconds.  Since I have enough free RAM, I'd like to put them in the cache so that the first people to query the data don't have a slightly slower experience than optimal.  The query in question which is the reason for me wanting to load things into the cache is detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649767/optimizing-a-sql-query-which-is-already-doing-an-index-seek?noredirect=1#comment36322795_23649767

Comment: A valid use case for this, I'd say.