# Optimizing a SQL Query which is already doing an index seek

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-performance

I have a SQL query which is pretty efficient, but I have a feeling it can be improved upon.

It's the 48% cost on the sort after the index seek using `IX_thing_time_location` that I would hope can be improved upon.  I would hate to think that this is the best that can be done with this query.  Is there anything else I can do to improve performance in terms of updating the query, changing my indexes, partitioning (I know these doesn't always mean performance gains)?

Here is the execution plan: http://pastebin.com/G4Zi2tnw

I tried to paste it in here, but it's too large.

Index definition:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_thing_time_location] ON [dbo].[tippy]
(
    [time_start] ASC,
    [location] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [id],
    [name],
    [time_end],
    [is_meetup],
    [utc_offset],
    [type],
    [all_day]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetthingsByLatLong]
@minLat FLOAT,
@maxLat FLOAT,
@minLong FLOAT,
@maxLong FLOAT,
@startTime BIGINT,
@endTime BIGINT
AS

SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude
INTO #templocations
FROM locations
WHERE latitude BETWEEN @minLat AND @maxLat
AND longitude BETWEEN @minLong AND @maxLong
ORDER BY id;

-- This is a container
-- Get all "routes" (containers) within a given lat/long combo
SELECT thing_routes.*
INTO #tempRoutes
FROM thing_routes
WHERE latitude BETWEEN @minLat AND @maxLat
AND longitude BETWEEN @minLong AND @maxLong;


-- Get all things which are in the above containers
SELECT tip.id, tip.name, tip.location, tip.time_start, tip.time_end, tip.is_meetup, 
tip.utc_offset, tip.[type], tip.all_day,
#tempRoutes.id AS route_id, locations.name AS location_name, 
locations.latitude AS latitude, locations.longitude AS longitude
INTO #tempRoute_things
FROM #tempRoutes
INNER JOIN link_thing_routes
ON link_thing_routes.route_id = #tempRoutes.id
INNER JOIN locations
ON locations.id = #tempRoutes.location
INNER JOIN thing AS tip
ON link_thing_routes.thing_id = tip.id;


-- Return the data
SELECT * FROM #tempRoutes


-- Return the data - Add in the things from external_thing_routes
-- Join the two tables from earlier, filtering on time
SELECT tip.id, tip.name, tip.location, tip.time_start, tip.time_end, tip.is_meetup, 
tip.utc_offset, tip.[type], tip.all_day, NULL as route_id, #templocations.name AS location_name,
#templocations.latitude AS latitude, #templocations.longitude AS longitude
FROM #templocations 
INNER MERGE JOIN thing AS tip
ON #templocations.id = tip.location 
WHERE time_start BETWEEN @startTime AND @endTime



SELECT external_thing_routes.thing_id, external_thing_routes.route_id
FROM external_thing_routes
```

Comment: What columns are contained in the [IX_thing_time_location] index.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne - I added it into the question.

Comment: Maybe look into how much I/O takes place and filtered indexes.

Comment: Maybe your query, not only execution plan would be useful...

Comment: @Justin - Added it to the question.  I only didn't add it this time as in the past I was told there is no point since it is included in the EP.  My bad, I'll be sure to always add both in the future :)

Comment: could you test with indexes on latitude, longtitude, id on locations and latitude, longtitude on thing_routes?

Comment: @Alfons - The slowness comes from the query below the comment `Join the two tables from earlier, filtering on time` - I added in the whole SP for reference.

Comment: Might performance be improved by putting the join into a view and indexing the view?

Comment: You could try and make the above index an clustered one, if inserting is of less of a speed concern than the query.  It will require dropping and recreating them (AND will be complicated if you have transaction replication on)

Comment: sorry, that one sorts on time_start, after some locations are removed. So it needs a index on location, time_start not time_start, location. The order of field in an index do matter, well they do in oracle and i doubt it works differently in mssql.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (non-express) - if so, you can use the index tuning wizard to suggest the optimal index in this case.  Just create a workload file with a few variations of your query.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne - According to the DTA, my indexes are optimal, but my queries take up to 3/4 seconds, and my gut tells me they should be quicker...  I'm using SQL Server 2012 (64bit - non-enterprise)

Comment: Have you thought about using a columnstore index.  I have not personally worked with it, but I am told it is much quicker.  On SQL 2012, you do need to use it only for reporting, i.e. it needs to be read-only (you can drop and recreate at will), but it may be worth investigating.  Attached link with some info:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3540.sql-server-columnstore-index-faq.aspx . Link may become invalid, but in-memory advancements will probably make this comment obsolete before it is complete... :)

Comment: INNER MERGE JOIN why you are forcing optimizer to choose merge join. that is causing to sort the data first and then matching the rows.

Comment: and hows the performance if you index your temp table`s column #templocations.id

Comment: @AnthonyHorne - Can't use a columnstore as my PK field is a float/dec with 38 point precision (18 is the upper limit for columnstore).  I could potentially drop it down to 18, but it would be risky, and I'd rather avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: You are really swimming an uphill battle.  I will think a bit more..

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma - Hash join is only faster on tiny amounts of data.  I'm just forcing the query to use the most optimal join type for the given query.  It saves a small amount of time during the first few calls to the SP as it (at first) has to decide on join type.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne - Hahahaha, I know.  I think the performance is decent, but as I said I think I can get more out of it.  If you think of anything, please do let me know, I want to squeeze as much out of this as possible.  If I need to redesign my PK field (I really don't want to do this), then I will have to.  The general speed of this query is just too slow :(

Comment: Really bad practice 
query optimizer always chooses best physical join base on the statistics on the table, here cardinality estimation is accurate so please don`t force it.. you are pushing it to go for sorting for both the tables. " Hash join is only faster on tiny amounts of data"
NO .. we should avoid these statements because it always depend on the rows into process and the available indexes on the column.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt look at the explain script, but i have bumped into similar problems.

Are the columns on which you sort in the same index as the selection? If you got a query like this:

```
select * 
from exampletable
where foreignkey = somevalue
order by column1, column2
```

One of the indexes should be

```
foreignkey, column1, column2
```